# Double clickable transparent panel in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm coding a MediaPlayer using the VLC Plugin and want to make vlc (WindowsFormsintegration) double clickable (for fullscreen). But there is no double click event. So I thought about a Clickable-transparent Panel which overlays the VLC (WFI). Can somebody help me ? I'm using WPF on Windows and switched form Winforms to WPF because of the lack of transparency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy enough to place a transparent item over another item in WPF.  The example WPF below shows a transparent border overlaying a button on a Grid control.

```
<Grid Background="#006000">
    <Button Content="clicky" Click="clicky"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30"/>
    <Border Background="#00FFFFFF" >
        <Border.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick "
                Command="{Binding CommandDoubleClick}"/>
        </Border.InputBindings>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image]

The `Border` element has a Double-Click command bound to it.

The problem with doing this is that the transparent `Border` overlaying the `Button` prevents the `Button` from being clicked.  You can't click through the `Border` element to get to the elements underneath it.  If you don't need to access anything under the transparent element, then this should work for you. If you do need to access the elements under the transparent item, then this won't work at all.

Shown below is the RelayCommand code and associated method that is bound to the double-click event on the border:

```
    private bool CanDoubleClick = true;
    RelayCommand commandDoubleClick;
    public ICommand CommandDoubleClick
    {
        get
        {
            if (commandDoubleClick == null)
            {
                commandDoubleClick = new RelayCommand(param => DoubleClickMethod(),
                param => CanDoubleClick);
            }
            return commandDoubleClick;
        }
    }

    private void DoubleClickMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Double-Clicked the Border");
    }
```

This code is placed in the ViewModel which is used for the DataContext of the Window containing the transparent border.  You'll want to do a little research on the MVVM design pattern, Relay Commands, and Binding.

Unfortunately, there is no double-click event directly accessible on a `Border` or other panel element that you can use, so that's why the more complicated InputBindings are needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do I add an Event like: if  the Border is double Clicked a MessageBox should appear with the text "You double clicked"

Comment: That's what the Command Binding is for.  Edited the answer to include the RelayCommand and associated method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Can I use the DoubleClickMethod in MainWindows.xaml.cs ??

Comment: I suppose you could put the `CommandDoubleClick` Command and `DoubleClickMethod` in MainWindows.xaml.cs and just do `DataContext = this` after `InitializeComponent` and skip the ViewModel.  You could give it a try, it should work.